# Multiple Custom Cell's in a ListView (Cross Platform)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently with ListView's I've only found that you can create a template for cells, which makes each cell look exactly the same. You can't have multiple custom cells in the listview. There are work-arounds like hiding the content in the cell depending on the content, but this seems pretty hacky.

The reason I want to use a listview over a tableview is because we plan on doing inserts, deletions, dynamically showing certain cells, and listview's can be binded to a data source.

Comment: What you need is a `DataTemplateSelector`. You can build one yourself easily, there is a lot of documentation for Windows Phone 8 version which you can use as the base code for your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own ViewCell which overrides binding context change method. When the binding changes set the ViewCell's view to one that matches the type of view model and also set the height of the cell. Below is a quick sample that should give you an idea how to accomplish it.

```
public class DataTemplateCell1 : ViewCell
{
    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        var vm1 = this.BindingContext as ViewModel1;
        if (vm1 != null)
        {
            this.View = new View1() { HeightRequest = 40 };
            this.Height = this.View.HeightRequest;
            return;
        }

        var vm2 = this.BindingContext as ViewModel2;
        if (vm2 != null)
        {
            this.View = new View2() { HeightRequest = 80 };
            this.Height = this.View.HeightRequest;
            return;
        }

        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
    }
}
```